# Не работает php-скрипт логина

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Почему-то не работает скрипт login.php. Не показывает никаких ошибок, ничего не выводится. Хотя, в скрипте это есть. В чем может быть ошибка?

```php
<?php 
session_start();
require_once 'connect.php';
require_once 'config.php';
if (isset($signInBtn)) 
{
  $erlog = array();
  $user = R::findOne('users', 'login = ?', array($login));
  if ($user) 
  {
    // логин есть, проверка пароля
    if (sha1($password) == $user->password) 
    {
      // пароль есть, залогинивание
      echo "ПАРОЛИ И ЛОГИН ВЕРНЫ";
    } 
    else 
    {
      $erLog[] = "Пароль введен неверно";
    }
  } 
  else 
  {
    $erLog[] = "Пользователя с таким именем не существует";
  }
  if (!empty($erlog)) {
    $_SESSION['message'] = array_shift($erLog);
  }
}
?>
```

А, вот еще список переменных:

```php
$login = $_POST['login'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$dpassword = $_POST['dpassword'];
$regButton = $_POST['doReg'];
$signInBtn = $_POST['signIn'];
```

Comment: что в error.log пишется?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все решилось очень просто. Допустимая длина значения в MySQL базе была меньше, чем длина хеша. Сравнение было неверным. Я изменил длину значения и все заработало!